# Scala function inside a filter loop not working (type mismatch)

Tags: scala

I'm new in Scala, I have a function (that works)

```
object Utiles {
  def func(param: String, param2: String): String = {
    // Do Somthing
    true
  }
}
```

In a different file, I'm using this function successfully, but when i insert it to a filter it gives me an error

```
list.filter(value => {
     Utiles.func(value.param ,value.param2)
})
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
type mismatch;
  found   : String
  required: None.type
             Utiles.func(value.param ,value.param2)
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why does your func return a String?

Comment: That function doesn't compile. Change the return type to `Boolean`

Comment: What is the type of the elements of the list?

Comment: Your function _doesn't_ work. There's no automatic implicit conversion between Boolean and String.

Comment: I think you are too new to scala, but filter takes a predicate and your function returns String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three issues here (that I can see as the question is currently written):

1. Your `func` function doesn't compile. You have put the return type of the function as `String`, yet you are returning a `Boolean` (true). Either change the return type, or end the function by returning a String.
2. `.filter(...)` requires you to make something either true or false. This will be fixed if you change the return type of `func` to be `Boolean`. If your return type is *supposed* to be `String`, you'll need to compare that `String` to something. Eg:

   ```
   List("foo", "bar").filter(x => func(x) == "baz")
   ```
3. Your type mismatch error is because you seem to be passing a `String` into your `func` function where it is expecting a `None.type` (for some reason).

What I'm getting at, is you have failed to give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I have debugged your code *as you have presented it*, but I have a strong feeling that you have tried to cut down your real function to a point where your errors (and the function itself) make no sense.

Comment: thanks, I used your second option and somehow it works and fixed my type mismatch

Answer (score 2):

If you noticed `filter` takes a predicate

```
def filter(p: A => Boolean): List[A]
```

which means your filter function on `List[SomeData]` should be `SomeData => Boolean`.

example:

```
scala> def fun(param1: String, param2: String): Boolean = param1 == param2
fun: (param1: String, param2: String)Boolean

scala> List("updupd", "whatwhat").filter(p => fun(p, "updupd"))
res0: List[String] = List(updupd)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're able to use `func` in a different place because the return type is wrong. It should be `Boolean`:

```
object Utiles {
  def func(param: String, param2: String): Boolean = {
    // Do Somthing
    true
  }
}
```